# Android Application working in Android 2 but throws exception in Android 4

Tags: android

I have an android app that runs good in Android 2 , but when I try to run it on Android 4,it crashes and throws exceptions. Bellow is the Log I get

```
11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753): java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.huda.elklob/com.example.huda.elklob.options}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error
 inflating class android.widget.Button 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 com.example.huda.elklob.options.onCreate(options.java:17) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     ... 11 more 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by:
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   ... 25 more 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
 11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 11-04
 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753):   at
 android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:449) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     at
 android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104) 11-04 16:50:01.015:
 E/AndroidRuntime(753):     ... 28 more
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Some code that might cause it could be helpful in finding the problem.

Comment: Thanks kmatyaszek for Editing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yech. Next time, please format your LogCat dump as "code" as opposed to "quote". At least the line breaks will be in their rightful places.

That said, the relevant bit is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-04 16:50:01.015: E/AndroidRuntime(753): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
```

Out of memory error while decoding a bitmap. Make it a smaller bitmap.

Comment: I will, thanks for your advice :)
I'll try to make the bitmap smaller,ok

Comment: I agree. For a more detailed analitical approach, you can also see my answer (if you're interested).

Comment: Thanks a lot Seva Alekseyev :) I made the bitmap smaller and it worked ;)

Comment: Welcome. Here at SO, we say thank by accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

As your log shows, the root of the error (exception) is an `OutOfMemoryError`. The bitmap is too large to fit in memory (i.e. you don't have enough space on the Dalvik managed heap for it). Moreover, it is possible that loading the bitmap requires more memory than storing it (see below).

It is very likely that in the display of your Android 4 device, your image requires more pixels than in case of your Android 2 device, and Android is scaling up the image in memory, resulting in an even higher memory consumption while the bitmap is loaded.

So either you need to make your bitmap smaller for this display type (i.e. for the display used by your Android 4 device too), or you can try to load and set the bitmap manually (see this [official page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) about loading large bitmaps).